# How to check if PFRelation in Parse contains exactly same array in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform

I am making a chat Application in ios through parse server. I have made a MessageRoom collection which has many to many relationship with users through PFRelation. Now i am struck . Whenever a user starts a new conversation , I add new entry in MessageRoom collection and use its id in the messages of that group. But when i want to fetch a previous conversation , let say a conversation between 5 users , how will i query the messageRoom which has exactly the same 5 users (not more or less) in its relation ?

This is the code i am using to create or get Message Room . It is not working correctly. What it does is instead of making a new messageRoom first time and fetching the same for latter user , it makes a new messaga room every time.

```
 class func createOrGetMessageRoom(users:[PFUser], description:String)->PFObject{

    var returnMessageRoom:PFObject = PFObject(className: PF_MESSAGE_ROOM_CLASS_NAME);
    let users = users.sort(increasingIDs)
    let query:PFQuery = PFQuery(className: PF_MESSAGE_ROOM_CLASS_NAME)

    query.whereKey(PF_MESSAGE_ROOM_USERS, containsAllObjectsInArray : users)

    query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock{(objects, error )->Void in
        if error == nil {
            if objects?.count == 0 {
                let messageRoom = PFObject(className: PF_MESSAGE_ROOM_CLASS_NAME)
                messageRoom[PF_MESSAGE_ROOM_DESCRIPTION] = description
                messageRoom[PF_MESSAGE_ROOM_LAST_USER] = PFUser.currentUser()
                messageRoom[PF_MESSAGE_ROOM_LAST_MESSAGE] = ""
                messageRoom[PF_MESSAGE_ROOM_COUNTER] = 0
                messageRoom[PF_MESSAGE_ROOM_UPDATE_TIME] = NSDate()
                let messageUsers = messageRoom.relationForKey(PF_MESSAGE_ROOM_USERS)
                for user in users {
                    messageUsers.addObject(user)
                }
                messageRoom.saveInBackgroundWithBlock{(success,error)->Void in
                    if error == nil {
                        returnMessageRoom = messageRoom
                    }
                }
            }else{
                returnMessageRoom = objects![0]
            }
        }else{
            print("Message.createMessage Erorr");
            print(error)
        }
    }
    return returnMessageRoom
}


 class func increasingIDs(user1: PFUser, user2: PFUser) -> Bool {
    return user1.objectId < user2.objectId
}
```

I have also checked [this application](https://github.com/huyouare/SwiftParseChat/tree/master/SwiftParseChat) . What it does is whenever it starts a new chat , it concatenates objectIds of users in ascending order and use it as a groupId which is used for future references and used in chat messages as a foreign key.

It'll work in private chat and in group chat , but what happens if a user has started a group chat , and wants to add new users to this chat ?? If we simple change the group id by concatenating this users id , the previous messages which have used the old group id will no longer appear in this message group.

Also tell me if this approach of making groupID through concatenation is better or many to many relationship is better?

Answer (score 0):

One problem with your function `createOrGetMessageRoom` is that `findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock` is **asynchronous**, and you're not taking that into account.

What this means is that the `findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock` function gets a response a long time after `createOrGetMessageRoom` has returned.
So, the `PFObject` you create on the first line of your function is always returned - your function does not wait for `findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock` to return a MessageRoom.

To fix this, make your code take a callback like this:

```
class func createOrGetMessageRoom(users:[PFUser], description:String, callback: (PFObject? -> Void)) {

    let users = users.sort(increasingIDs)
    let query:PFQuery = PFQuery(className: PF_MESSAGE_ROOM_CLASS_NAME)

    query.whereKey(PF_MESSAGE_ROOM_USERS, containsAllObjectsInArray : users)

    query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock{(objects, error )->Void in
        if error == nil {
            if objects?.count == 0 {
                let messageRoom = PFObject(className: PF_MESSAGE_ROOM_CLASS_NAME)
                messageRoom[PF_MESSAGE_ROOM_DESCRIPTION] = description
                messageRoom[PF_MESSAGE_ROOM_LAST_USER] = PFUser.currentUser()
                messageRoom[PF_MESSAGE_ROOM_LAST_MESSAGE] = ""
                messageRoom[PF_MESSAGE_ROOM_COUNTER] = 0
                messageRoom[PF_MESSAGE_ROOM_UPDATE_TIME] = NSDate()
                let messageUsers = messageRoom.relationForKey(PF_MESSAGE_ROOM_USERS)
                for user in users {
                    messageUsers.addObject(user)
                }
                messageRoom.saveInBackgroundWithBlock{(success,error)->Void in
                    if error == nil {
                        callback(messageRoom)
                    }
                    callback(nil)
                }
            }else{
                callback(objects![0])
            }
        }else{
            print("Message.createMessage Erorr");
            print(error)
            callback(nil)
        }
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
YourClass.createOrGetMessageRoom([], description: "description") { messageRoom in
    // Do something...   
}
```

Comment: Hi paulvs , Thanks for pointing it out but the issue still persists. Still it is making a new message Room for every message

Comment: If you add a breakpoint just inside `findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock` and step forward, what happens?

Comment: It is giving 0 objects. But if i change containsAllObjectsInArray to containedIn it returns the objects but i think it will also return messageRooms which have other users also in addition to these.

Comment: Are you sure then you have objects saved in parse with the users IDs you are querying for?

Comment: Yes the relations are appearing in mongo db console (i have set up parse server and mongo db in docker). The only thing i am unable to do is how to fetch a messageRoom which has exactly same users

Say i am looking for chat of **users A,B and C**

//only this message room should be returned
**{A,B,C}**  

//These should not match the criteria
**{A,B} 
{A,B,C,D}**

Answer (score 0):

The db schema in my mind, you should have 3 collections, _User, MessageRoom, and Message.

MessageRoom: users, roomName and other infos.

Message: room(pointer of MessageRoom), msg(content), sender(pointer of _User)

below are pseudo code

In your app, query all current user involved messageRooms.

```
var query = new Parse.Query("MessageRoom")
query.equalTo("users", currentUser);
//other constraint, roomName, createdAt, limit ...
query.find(...)
```

Pick a messageRoom object, and then use it to getMessages.

```
var query2 = new Parse.Query("Message");
query2.eqaulTo("room", roomObj);
query2.include("sender");
query2.descending("createdAt");
query2.find(...)
```